# Apply any type of a variable to another in python

Tags: python, types, casting

I would like to know if it is possible in Python to "extract" the constructor type (metaclass?) from a variable in order to use it to type-cast another variable to the same type, programatically, without having to have any "prior expectation" regarding the types we can encounter.

If it is more meaningful that way, the implementation would be something in the realm of:

```
def copyType(destination_var,source_var):
   try:
     type_class = way_to_get_the_type_metaclass(source_var)
     return typeclass(destination_var)
   # as if we did str(destination_var) or int(destination_var) or 
   # any other class, but without having to have expectation and being forced to check
   # if isinstance(var, str) : elif isinstance(var,int) : .... and so on
   except :
      raise TypeError

variable1 = "157"
variable2 = 34
print(type(variable1))
print(type(variable2))

variable2 = copyType(variable2 ,variable1)
print(type(variable2))

>>> Out : <str>
          <int>
          <str>
```

Comment: Usually `type(variable1)(variable2)`

Comment: Or alternatively, `variable1.__class__(variable2)` (does the same thing as tobias's suggestion; opinions differ on which is prettier/more "pythonic")

Comment: @tobias Wow, so simple. Why did i not think to to it that way. Now that i see it, seems so obvious... I guess I was so used to see type() function's result only as a string printed here and there that i forgot it returned an object. Thank you !

Comment: @AlexWaygood I think opinion is pretty strongly against the direct use of dunder attributes when avoidable.

Comment: Python doesn't really have casting. You aren't just telling Python to treat an existing value as if it had a different type; you are creating an entirely *new* value from the old. (In certain situations, you *can* do something similar by directly *assigning* a new value to an object's `__class__` attribute, but I can't really think of a situation where that would be advisable.)

Comment: `__class__`, I believe,  is an implementation detail of CPython, not something the language promises will be set.

Comment: Okay, so if i understand everything correctly, doing type(variable1)(variable2) (or the other suggestion, for wich the left part of the expression basically retrieves the same object) means that under the hood the constructor class of the object variable1, \_\_init\_\_ , is called with variable2 as argument. So the "mimic" of a type casting here is depending on how \_\_init\_\_ will treat a specific argument type, and values, and so may be different for each specific pair of classes / values. Wich is no problem for what I intent to do by the way.

Comment: @Osamoele you are correct. If we have a variable `x = 5`, then the `type` of that variable (and its `class`, they are one and the same) is `int`. Since `type(x) -> int`, `type(x)("10")` and `x.__class__("10")` will both produce the exact same result as `int("10")`. Since the `int` constructor knows how to make numbers from strings in some cases, they will all result in a new `int` object being constructed, with value `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by tobias and Alex Waygood in the comments, the solution is as simple as:

```
type(variable1)(variable2)
```

or

```
variable1.__class__(variable2)
```